# How to Enable One Login in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on redmine application I need to integrate one login with redmine application.

Can anybody assist me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Single Authentication(SSO) plugin](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/single_auth) to implement one-time login for Redmine application.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a plugin for SAML, which I forked and corrected to work with onelogin, you can grab it [here](https://github.com/acosonic/redmine_omniauth_saml)

1. Add redmine app to your onelogin company account
2. Checkout plugin from my github `git clone https://github.com/acosonic/redmine_omniauth_saml`
3. Follow the instructions from github's readme.
   You need to copy sample initializer.rb to /path/to/your/redmine/config/initalizers and rename it to onelogin.rb
4. Paste the values from Onelogin's SSO tab to onelogin.rb
   [[image: Onelogin's SSO tab[2]]
5. Install plugin by typing `bundle exec rake redmine:plugins  RAILS_ENV=production`
6. Restart redmine and configure your plugin under **Administration | Plugins | Redmine omniauth SAML | Configuration**
7. Enter some name like "Onelogin"
8. Test the installation (you should see Onelogin button) at Redmine's login page, clicking it will take you to Onelogin you enter Onelogin username and password and you are redirected back to Redmine

> There is also option to enable new user registration, you need to
>   enable it if users don't exist in Redmine already!

Sample onelogin intializer under Redmine config:

```
config.saml = {
:assertion_consumer_service_url => "http://redminecookbook.com/auth/saml/callback", # OmniAuth callback URL
:issuer                         => "https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/111111",                    # The issuer name / entity ID. Must be an URI as per SAML 2.0 s$
:idp_sso_target_url             => "https://acosonic.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/111111", # SSO login endpoint
:idp_cert_fingerprint           => "AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:6A:6A:FA:DA:2D:03:05:2B:94", # SSO ssl certificate fingerprint
# Alternatively, specify the full certifiate:
#:idp_cert                       => "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----",
:name_identifier_format         => "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent",
:signout_url                    => "https://acosonic.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-redirect/slo/111111", # Optional signout URL, not supported by all identity provide$
:idp_slo_target_url             => "https://acosonic.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-redirect/slo/111111",
:name_identifier_value          => "mail", # Which redmine field is used as name_identifier_value for SAML logout
:attribute_mapping              => {
# How will we map attributes from SSO to redmine attributes
  :login      => 'extra.raw_info.username',
  :mail       => 'extra.raw_info.email',
  :firstname  => 'extra.raw_info.firstname',
  :lastname   => 'extra.raw_info.lastname'
}
```

}

If above is not detailed enough, read [this](http://www.redminecookbook.com/blog-30-Configuring-Redmine-authenticaiton-with-onelogin) blog post.